# Why does "mouse_event" not work well with "Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left"?

Tags: c#

I'm using Winforms to make a simple hold-to-click autoclicker.
This is my code for a timer that executes every time the program wants to click:

```
if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
    uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}
```

The problem is the program when it autoclicks lifts the mouse up, which makes "Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left" confused because the autoclicker keeps unclicking the mouse, even though I'm actually holding it down. I tried testing it without the mouse being held and it worked so the mouse_event is actually working.

Is there a way to check if I'm **physically** holding the mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: I would always use HasFlags(MouseButtons.Left) instead of testing for equality, but that may not be the issue..